# Unable to send Firebase push notification via remote server

Tags: java, spring, firebase-cloud-messaging

I have a springboot project and added firebase dependency and all related things.
When I run the project locally, everything works fine.
I am using firebase admin sdk to send notifications.
The code for sending is:

```
try {
    messagingService.send(message);
    logger.info("Firebase notification sent to user: "+user.getUsername());
    saveLog(true, "Notification Sent", pushNotificationLog);
    return true;
}catch (FirebaseMessagingException e) {
    logger.info("Firebase did not send notification to user: "+user.getUsername()+ " Error Message: "+e.getMessage());
    saveLog(false, e.getMessage(), pushNotificationLog);
    return false;
}
```

As soon as I do the same on my remote server with different application properties, I get the exception while sending the notification, this is what it says:

> 2024-03-18 07:27:14.759  INFO 1 --- [nio-8091-exec-4] c.p.service.FirebaseNotificationService  : Firebase did not send notification to user: zubair Error Message: Unknown error while making a remote service call: Error getting access token for service account: java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: Error constructing implementation (algorithm: Default, provider: SunJSSE, class: sun.security.ssl.SSLContextImpl$DefaultSSLContext), iss: firebase-adminsdk-b545a@bol3-c8b35.ibm.gserviceaccount.com

I have used cryptographic algos in some places of my code and they are working fine, only this isn't.

I tried running my local with the application properties of the remote server and it worked fine. I am unable to figure out the issue.

[image: Complete Exception part 1]
[image: part 2]
[image: part 3]
[image: part 4]
[image: part 5]